# Make Search Box Centre

Tags: css, html, centering

This should be a relatively easy question. Though I am yet to find a solution as I'm a beginner. All I would like to do is center my search box. The html is as follows:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUCqn/)

```html
  <div class="colums">
    <li class="share"> <a target="_blank" href="#"></a>

    </li>
    <div id='search-box'>
      <form action='/search' id='search-form' method='get' target='_top'>
        <input onwebkitspeechchange="voiceInputOver(this.value)" x-webkit-speechname='q'
        placeholder='Search Contrabang...' type='text' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colums">
    <div class="cntratop">
      <ul>
        <li class="live"> <a target="_blank" href="#">+Contrabang</a>

        </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Blog</a>

        </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Events</a>

        </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columa">
    <div id="text-display"> <span>Your Daily Dose of Contrabang</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```css
.columa {
  background:transparent;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.colums {
  background:transparent;
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.cntratop {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.cntratop ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin-top:12px;
  background:;
  width:760px;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.cntratop li {
  display:inline-block;
}
.cntratop li:first-child {
  margin-left:0px;
}
/*navbar text*/
 .cntratop a {
  display:inline;
  margin-left: -9px;
  padding:15px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#999;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.cntratop a:hover,
/*
.cntratopli.live*/
 a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#E94F78;
}
#search-box {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right:0px;
}
#search-form {
  width:0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
#search-box input[type="text"] {
  width: 760px;
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 90.0%;
  padding: 3px 2 2px 10px;
  color: #999;
  outline: none;
}
#search-text {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-style: italic;
  border-width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
#search-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 32px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#text-display {
  background-color:#E94F78;
}
#text-display {
  top:;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#search-form {
  /* width:0px; */
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
```

Removing the `width:0px` from `#search-form` should resolve this problem. The `text-align:center` style, within your `.colums` class, appears to control the alignment of the search input.

Hope that helps :)